# Vectorizing loop with running value that depends on previous value (+ if statement)

Tags: python, numba

I'm accustomed to writing vectorized statements and list comprehensions in Python, but I've got a problem that appears with both a "running" computation that depends on the previous value in the loop, as well as an if statement.  Schematically it looks like this:

```
def my_loop(x, a=0.5, b=0.9):
  out = np.copy(x)
  prev_val = 0 
  for i in np.arange(x.shape[0]):

      if x[i] < prev_val:
          new_val = (1-a)*x[i] + a*prev_val
      else:
          new_val = (1-b)*x[i] + b*prev_val

      out[i] = new_val

      prev_val = new_val

  return out
```

I haven't been able to figure out how one could vectorize this (e.g. via using some kind of accumulator), so I'll ask:  Is there a way to make this more Pythonic/faster?

I've seen previous posts about vectorizing when there's an if statement -- usually solved via np.where() -- but not one where there's a "running" value that depends on its previous state...so I haven't found any duplicate questions yet (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705933/vectorize-numpy-code-with-operation-depending-on-previous-value) isn't about vectorization in the usual sense, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150804/loops-index-that-depends-on-a-previous-one) is about 'previous value' but referring to list indices).

So far, I have tried `np.vectorize` and numba's `@jit`, and they do run somewhat faster, but neither gives me the speed I'm hoping for.  Is there something I'm missing? (Maybe something with `map()`?) Thanks.

(Yes, in the case of a=b this becomes easy!)

Comment: I doubt you will get much performance gain with ``np.vectorize``. Quoting from the docs - "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that by removing dummy variables, this code could be put into a form where numba and `@autojit` could work their magic and make it "fast":

```
from numba import jit, autojit

@autojit
def my_loop4(x, a=0.5, b=0.9):
  out = np.zeros(x.shape[0],dtype=x.dtype)
  for i in np.arange(x.shape[0]):
      if x[i] < out[i-1]:
          out[i] = (1-a)*x[i] + a*out[i-1]
      else:
          out[i] = (1-b)*x[i] + b*out[i-1]
  return out
```

Without the @autojit, this is still painfully slow.  But with it on,...problem solved.  So, removing the unnecessary variables *and* adding @autojit is what did the trick.

Comment: Don't use `np.arange(x.shape[0])`. This creates an array, but you want a simpile iterator like range (Python3) or xrange(Python2)

Answer (score 1):

JITing in nopython mode is faster. Quoting from numba docs:

> Numba has two compilation modes: nopython mode and object mode. The
> former produces much faster code, but has limitations that can force
> Numba to fall back to the latter. To prevent Numba from falling back,
> and instead raise an error, pass nopython=True.

```
@nb.njit(cache=True)
def my_loop5(x, a=0.5, b=0.9):
  out = np.zeros(x.shape[0],dtype=x.dtype)
  
  for i in range(x.shape[0]):
      if x[i] < out[i-1]:
          out[i] = (1-a) * x[i] + a * out[i-1]
      else:
          out[i] = (1-b) * x[i] + b * out[i-1]
  return out
```

So that on:

```
x = np.random.uniform(low=-5.0, high=5.0, size=(1000000,))
```

The timing are :

> my_loop4 : 0.235s
>
> my_loop5 : 0.193s

HTH.

Comment: Interesting, hey thanks for trying this. When I compare autojit with njit, the latter is about the same but a bit slower.   41.1 µs per loop for autojit  vs. 41.2 µs per loop for njit.

Comment: @sh37211 Try on larger inputs, as their is compile time also included, or time on second run after the compiled code is cached.